# How can I extract just the value of a tag without the name using exiftool?

Tags: software, metadata, exiftool

I am trying to save the camera make to a variable in my Bash script. If I use:

```
exiftool -make x.jpg
```

This returns:

```
MAKE : SAMSUNG
```

I need it to return just the value, without the key and colon.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [man page](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#s-NUM--short):

```
-s[NUM] (-short)

    Short output format. Prints tag names instead of descriptions.
    Add NUM or up to 3 -s options for even shorter formats:

       -s1 or -s        - print tag names instead of descriptions
       -s2 or -s -s     - no extra spaces to column-align values
       -s3 or -s -s -s  - print values only (no tag names)

-S (-veryShort)
    Very short format. The same as -s2 or two -s options.
    Tag names are printed instead of descriptions, and no extra
    spaces are added to column-align values.
```

So, any of the following will work:

```
exiftool -s -s -s -make x.jpg

exiftool -s3 -make x.jpg

exiftool -s -S -make x.jpg
```

Note that combining multiple `-s` options into `-sss`, such as increasing `-v`/`-vv`/`-vvv` verbosity in some Linux/Unix command line utilities such as `tcpdump`, will not work.

Answer (score 11):

Use `-b`:

```
$ exiftool -b -make x.jpg
```

From the man page:

> **-b (-binary)**
>
> Output requested metadata in binary format without tag names or descriptions.
>     This option is mainly used for extracting embedded images or other binary data,
>     but it may also be **useful for some text strings since control characters (such
>     as newlines) are not replaced by '.'** as they are in the default output.  List
>     items are separated by a newline when extracted with the -b option.  May be
>     combined with "-j", "-php" or "-X" to extract binary data in JSON, PHP or XML
>     format.

Highlight mine; it does what it says on the tin!

Comment: That's great for extraction decimal GPS values! Thanks!

Comment: To get the name of your tag, use `exiftool -s your.jpg`. With `-s` you get tag names that don't contain spaces. See also [this](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q2).

Answer (score 4):

The `-T` option will hide the tag name, so you get only the value (example with a different tag `ImageDescription`):

```
exiftool -s -T -ImageDescription $HOME/Downloads/2023-02-15_HippoDayChobe.jpg
```