# How do I use exiftool to strip all exif tags except rotation?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, rotation

I need the exact opposite of [How to remove orientation attribute from the photo without touching other exif-data?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99586/how-to-remove-orientation-attribute-from-the-photo-without-touching-other-exif-d)

I *want* to keep the EXIF rotation data, but I want to strip the rest of the data. Obviously I can use `exiftool -all= file.jpg` but that will remove the orientation data as well, which is undesirable.

Is there a way to keep only the rotation data with exiftool? I could use [exiftran](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftran) or something similar, but I'd rather just leave only the rotation data.

Comment: You might also want to keep colour profiles in the image's metadata so that the colours are displayed is intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432580/how-to-remove-exif-data-from-image-but-keep-the-orientation)

```
exiftool -all:all= -tagsfromfile @ -exif:Orientation /path/to/files
```

`-all:all=` removes all data, then `Orientation` is copied back into the file with the [`-TagsFromFile` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#tagsFromFile-SRCFILE-or-FMT).

Do **not** run this command on RAW files (NEF, ARW, CR2, etc.; see [Exiftool FAQ #8](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q8)). This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

Answer (score -2):

A bit of a hack, but if you're on a Unix-like system, you can use backticks to re-inject the desired value into the image:

```
exiftool -all= -Orientation=`exiftool -b -Orientation file.jpg` file.jpg
```

Note that the `-b` flag is important so that the tag value is outputed without the tag name (see [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56677/how-can-i-extract-just-the-value-of-a-tag-without-the-name-using-exiftool) for more).